# How to get the file dragged by the mouse?

Tags: go

I don't need to drop the file, I want to get the file (folder) path when dragged. Because the current interface library (Wails) I use can't get the real path of the file.I'm currently using a message loop, but I didn't find out how to get the dragged file

I used this library "github.com/lxn/win"

Do you have any good suggestions? thanks.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/wailsapp/wails/issues/1090)?

Comment: To elaborate on my comment, since that "wails" thing appears like an attempt to use WWW browsing technology to provide an UI for a locally running Go process, I reckon the problem is that in a traditional WWW paradigm the client and the server run on different machines and full pathnames as found on the client have no sense when interpreted on the server. I'd conjure that a way to go would be to find a client-side (that is, JS) lib which could allow somehow obtaining the full pathname of a DnD'ed file. This full pathname could then be sent to the server side.

Comment: @kostix Based on browser security considerations, it is impossible for js to obtain the real path，So it can only be achieved with winapi. I read that question too, but it doesn't work

Comment: In either case, [the project has enabled Discussions](https://github.com/wailsapp/wails/discussions) so I'd ask there.

Comment: «it can only be achieved with winapi»—I cannot compherend this argument: when your Go "server-side" process receives a relative pathname, it cannot, by definition, have any way to interpret it—using WinAPI or otherwise—except for _knowing_ which path was "current" for the file picker browser's component the user used to select a file. Since that path supposedly can be any at all, there's no way to know that.

Comment: Well, in theory, there are ways to control/monitor other processes—provided you have sufficient permissions, but consider this: if you're about to resorting to this level of unportable hacks to work around fundamental limitations of the WWW paradigm when applied to a local system, why use it at all? Not that the situation with GUI toolkits in Go is as good as with, say, C#/.NET, but solutions exist: Go has bindings to all major cross-platform GUI toolkits as well as custom stuff like Fyne.

Comment: @kostix I didn't explain clearly enough. This is not a web application, nor is it intended to be cross-platform. Just use web technology to do GUI, there may be other solutions, but a lot of programs have been developed. Wails official said that the function of obtaining the path may be added in the future, but it cannot be expected to be solved in the near future. Therefore, only winapi can be used to obtain the file path dragged by the mouse. js can only send the file itself to the backend, but will not give you the local path